# Cannot change ownership to uid 1001, gid 1001: Invalid argument

Tags: permissions, compiling, tar, cifs, ownership

I'm installing ONOS and following this guide: https://wiki.onosproject.org/display/ONOS/Developer+Quick+Start

I executed the command

```
sudo bazel build onos
```

This will compile and assemble the installable onos.tar.gz, which is located in the bazel-bin directory.

But I get the following error:

```
tar: apache-karaf-4.2.6/examples/karaf-war-example: Cannot change ownership to uid 1001, gid 1001: Invalid argument
```

I know some people resolved this in this page, and it has to do with CIFS: https://www.krenger.ch/blog/linux-tar-cannot-change-ownership-to-permission-denied/

They used the parameter --no-same-owner with the command tar

```
# tar xzf $INPUT_FOLDER/archive.tar.gz --no-same-owner -C /mnt/test-nas/[..]
```

The problem is, that in my case, tar is used by bazel, I'm not calling tar from the superuser, bazel is using tar and it fails. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding user/group to the system with the uid/gid might fix your problem. Rename **foobar** to bazel or whatever

Add group **foobar** with gid 1001

```
sudo groupadd -g 1001 foobar
```

Adding user **foobar** with uid 1001 without a home directory

```
sudo useradd -M -u 1001 -g 1001 foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `--no-same-owner` to the script where it is running `tar`:

- Edit the package script:

  ```
  vim /opt/onos/tools/package/onos-prep-karaf
  ```
- change line 22 to:

  ```
  tar xf $KARAF_TAR --no-same-owner
  ```

and then run

```
sudo bazel build onos
```

again.

Answer (score 0):

You must have found the solution since, but for those (like me) beginning with Onos :
if you install the developper version using bazel, you must use ubuntu desktop (tried with ubuntu 20, it's ok). Using an ubuntu server will lead to this error. It's written in the documentation but i didn't read well the first time :D

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you user448862. Could you [edit] your question to link to the relevant part(s) of the documentation that explain the Ubuntu Desktop vs Ubuntu Server requirement?